# Google Drive API zipped file corrupted

Tags: javascript, drive

Unable to open the zip file because corrupted after downloaded from Google Drive REST api.
Code as follow:

```
gapi.client.drive.files.get({'fileId':id,alt:'media'}).then((res)=>{
   const zipblob = new Blob([res.body])
   let a = document.createElement('a')
   a.download = 'sample.zip'
   a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(zipblob)
   a.click()
}
```

Response header from Drive REST API as follow:

```
Content-Type: "application/zip"
cache-control: "private, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
content-length: "216"
content-type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
date: "Tue, 12 Mar 2019 04:40:39 GMT"
expires: "Tue, 12 Mar 2019 04:40:39 GMT"
server: "UploadServer"
vary: "Origin, X-Origin"
x-guploader-uploadid: "AEnB2Upp9nbCpCrydypTCBqEH-Yc8p7cpRbvDLBGyxb9t4n1TRGux7Zcvw_2fSd3ibEav2q4cw6luDRoMNwzc5ytX57LsEwHbg"
```

---

I've found out a solution somewhere and it's working.

```
function str2bytes(str){
   var bytes = new Uint8Array(str.length)
   for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
      bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
   }
   return bytes;
}

gapi.client.drive.files.get({'fileId':id,alt:'media'}).then((res)=>{
   const zipblob = new Blob([str2bytes(res.body)])
   let a = document.createElement('a')
   a.download = 'sample.zip'
   a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(zipblob)
   a.click()
})
```

Comment: There's not really much to go on here. At 216 bytes, the file seems a bit small. Have you tried opening it in a text / hex editor?

Comment: @Phil, I created a file with only content of "asdfasdf", compressed and uploaded to my Google Drive for this testing. That's why the file's size is only 216bytes. I found out the solution somewhere and it's working. No idea why it's working as I still only a novice programmer. Thanks for helping by the way.